# Read data from a helper class' thread subclass

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback, runnable

I'm trying to create a NFC reader on a helper class, made on a thread subclass which runs the code which calls a device API. I've been looking lots of questions already and code examples on the Internet but I can't figure how to do this.

I have the activity class, the helper class which I initialize on the activity and the subclass runnable at the helper.

### Activity example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView textView = ...
    
    {some kind of callback which updates data (the TextView, for example)}
}
```

### Helper class:

```java
public class N1PUtil {

    AtomicBoolean nfcActive = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void openNfc(){

        nfcActive.set(true);
        "run NfcThread()";

    }

    public void closeNfc(){

        nfcActive.set(false);

    }
}
```

### Thread subclass:

```java
class NfcThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (nfcActive.get()) {
                
                readStuff;
                sendStuffToActivityClass();
                
            }
        }
}
```

Since I would execute this NfcReader from many activities, I thought this approach would be a nice option. **How could I manage this kind of communication between the three classes?** I'm pretty new to managing threads. Thank you very much.